# How to show an div when other div is not visible in the screen using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need  to show the `div#myDiv-1` when the `div#myDiv-2` is not visible in the screen using jquery

When the page load the `div#myDiv-2` is visible, then when the visitor **scroll down** and the `div#myDiv-2` is not visible anymore the `div#myDiv-1` is show up.

Sorry I don't post any code but I don't know how to start.

Comment: visible, like in display none, or visible like not visible on the users screen right now ?

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
$(function(){
    $('div#myDiv-2').show();
    $('div#myDiv-1').hide();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       if($('div#myDiv-2').is(":visible"))
       {
           $('div#myDiv-1').show();// shows the first div
           $('div#myDiv-2').hide();// hide the second div
       }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mztq/)

Comment: you could use `.is(":visible")` instead, as checking for css properties is not really ideal as there are 2 ways to hide/show elements (`display` and `visibility`)

Comment: @badZoke - `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` is considered visible when using `.is(":visible")`, so that does'nt do much good ?

Comment: I can't get it working. Should I put the firt 2 lines in a `$(document).ready(function()` function?

Comment: @Jaso2970 I don't know what you have tried but I tested it and it works. Check my answer again with the working fiddle.

Comment: @RohanKuma I checked on fiddle and it is not working right. The div-1 is shown at the very first step of the scrolling, not when div-2 is completely hidden. Since this will be hard to explain, I've made this 30secs video: http://www.screencast.com/t/wXc1wBm94t4T. Look that the div is shown even when div-2 is in the screen.

Comment: @Jaso2970 Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You could do this,

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(!$("#myDiv-2").is(":visible")){
         $("#myDiv-1").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `hide` event:

```
$('#myDiv-2').on('hide',function(){
    $('#myDiv-1').show();
});
```

Comment: Would be fun to see if you can get that working in a fiddle ?

Comment: Will this work when the element is hidden by doing scrolling??

Comment: @Jaso2970 - I think you should answer my comment on the question? By hidden, do you mean it just gets scrolled of the screen, and you can no longer see it on your screen, or are you actually hiding it with code ?

Comment: @adeneo When the div is scrolled off the screen (not hiding with code)

Comment: @Jaso2970 so it is not 'hidden' it's just off-sceen this code wont work  sorry ...

Answer (score 0):

To make one element appear when another element is scrolled of the screen, you can do:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y  = $(window).scrollTop(),
        e1 = $('#myDiv-1'),
        e2 = $('#myDiv-2'),
        vi = e1.offset().top < (y + $(window).height()) && (e1.offset().top + e1.height()) > y;

    e2.toggle(!vi);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RYZ3h/1/)

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(window).on') Line: 88` Line 88 is the last line of your code. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Jaso2970 - What version of jQuery, it's 2.0 now ?